# Ошибка Spring : Failed to load ApplicationContext в JUnit

Tags: java, spring, юнит-тесты, junit

**Вот что пишет**

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
    22:53:37.957 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6941827a] to prepare test instance [com.training.services.UserServiceTest@5a7005d]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:?]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:?]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:?]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:?]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:?]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:?]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'certificateServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.training.dataaccess.dao.CertificateDao com.training.services.impl.CertificateServiceImpl.certificateDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.training.dataaccess.dao.CertificateDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.training.dataaccess.dao.CertificateDao com.training.services.impl.CertificateServiceImpl.certificateDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.training.dataaccess.dao.CertificateDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.training.dataaccess.dao.CertificateDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 25 more
```

**классы которые я использую в тесте:**

```
package com.training.services.impl;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.training.dataaccess.dao.UserDao;
import com.training.dataaccess.model.Group;
import com.training.dataaccess.model.User;
import com.training.services.UserService;

@Component
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public void insertOrUpdate(User user) {
        if (user.getId() == null) {
            userDao.insert(user);
        } else {
            userDao.update(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void registerUser(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String groupName,
            String facultyName, Long minGda) {
        User user = new User();

        GroupServiceImpl gService = new GroupServiceImpl();
        FacultyServiceImpl fServise = new FacultyServiceImpl();

        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setFirstName(firstName);
        user.setLastName(lastName);
        user.setCreationDate(new Date());
        user.setGroupId(null);
        Long commonId = userDao.insertAndGetId(user);

        gService.insertGroup(groupName, commonId);

        fServise.insertFaculty(facultyName, commonId, minGda);
        gService.insertGroup(groupName, commonId);
        // send email
    }

    @Override
    public User get(Long id) {
        return userDao.getById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void userAdd2Group(User user, Group group) {
        userDao.updateGroupId(user, group);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdminTrue(User user) {
        userDao.setAdmin(user);

    }
}
```

**-----**

```
 package com.training.services.impl;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.training.dataaccess.dao.GroupDao;
    import com.training.dataaccess.model.Group;
    import com.training.services.GroupService;

    @Component
    public class GroupServiceImpl implements GroupService {

        @Autowired
        private GroupDao groupDao;

        @Override
        public Group get(Long id) {
            return groupDao.getById(id);
        }

        @Override
        public void insertGroup(String name, Long facultyId) {
          Group group = new Group();
          group.setName(name);

            groupDao.insert(group);
        }

    }
```

**-----**

```
package com.training.services.impl;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.training.dataaccess.model.Group;
    import com.training.services.FacultyService;

    @Component
    public class FacultyServiceImpl implements FacultyService {

        @Autowired
        private FacultyService facultyDao;

        @Override
        public Group get(Long id) {

            return facultyDao.get(id);
        }

        @Override
        public void insertFaculty(String name, Long groupId, Long minGda) {
            facultyDao.insertFaculty(name, groupId, minGda);
        }

    }
```

**сам тест**

```
package com.training.services;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.training.dataaccess.model.User;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:spring-db-context.xml")
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserService uService;

    @Test
    public void UserService() {

        String firstName = RandomStringUtils.random(255);
        String lastName = RandomStringUtils.random(255);
        String email = RandomStringUtils.random(255);
        String password = RandomStringUtils.random(255);
        String groupName = RandomStringUtils.random(255);

        uService.registerUser(firstName, lastName, email, password, groupName, groupName, 5L);
        uService.registerUser(firstName, lastName, email,  password, groupName, groupName, 5L);

        User registeredUser = uService.get(1l);
        User registeredUser2 = uService.get(1l);

        Assert.assertEquals(registeredUser, registeredUser2);

    }

}
```

**spring-db-context.xml лежит в dataaccess.src/main/resources, вот что в нём:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.training.dataacces" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.training.services" />
    <!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


  <!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type 
        DataSourceTransactionManager -->
   <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="com.training.dataaccess.util.SchemaNameAwareBasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="schema" value="${db.schema}" />
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder
        ignore-unresolvable="true" location="classpath:app.properties" />

</beans>
```

**upd class CertificateServiceImpl**

```
 package com.training.services.impl;

    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.training.dataaccess.dao.CertificateDao;
    import com.training.dataaccess.model.Certificate;
    import com.training.dataaccess.model.User;
    import com.training.services.CertificateService;

    @Component
    public class CertificateServiceImpl implements CertificateService {

        @Autowired
        private CertificateDao certificateDao;

        @PostConstruct
        private void init() {

        }

        @Override
        public void insertOrUpdate(Certificate certificate) {
            if (certificate.getId() == null) {
                certificateDao.insert(certificate);
            } else {
                certificateDao.update(certificate);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void addCertificate2User(User user, Certificate certificate) {
            certificateDao.setUserId(user);

        }

        @Override
        public Certificate get(Long id) {
            return certificateDao.getById(id);
        }

        @Override
        public void fillCertificate(Long id, String subject, Integer mark) {
            certificateDao.updateMarkAndSubject(id, subject, mark);
        }

    }
```

Но в CertificateServiceImpl `@Autowired` стоит, и  `@Component` тоже

```
**CertificateDaoImpl**

package com.training.dataaccess.dao.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.training.dataaccess.dao.CertificateDao;
import com.training.dataaccess.dao.mapper.CertificateMapper;
import com.training.dataaccess.model.Certificate;
import com.training.dataaccess.model.User;

@Repository
public class CertificateDaoImpl implements CertificateDao {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public Certificate getById(Long id) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from certificate where id = ?", new Object[] { 1 },
                new CertificateMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(Certificate certificate) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO certificate(mark, subject) VALUES (?,?)", certificate.getMark(),
                certificate.getSubject());
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Certificate certificate) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE certificate SET mark=?,subject=? where id=?", certificate.getMark(),
                certificate.getSubject(), certificate.getId());

    }

    @Override
    public void setUserId(User user) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE certificate SET user_id=?",user.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Certificate certificate) {

        jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE certificate WHERE id=?", certificate.getId());

    }

    @Override
    public void updateMarkAndSubject(Long id, String subject, Integer mark) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE certificate SET mark=?,subject=? where id=?", id,subject,mark);

    }

}
```

Где-то в `certificateServiceImpl` или в `certificateDao` ошибка, но найти чего-то не могу

```
    Error creating bean with name 'certificateServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
 nested exception is `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`:
 Could not autowire field: private `com.training.dataaccess.dao.CertificateDao` `com.training.services.impl.CertificateServiceImpl.certificateDao`;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
 No qualifying bean of type [`com.training.dataaccess.dao.CertificateDao`]
 found for dependency:
 expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
 Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Спасибо заранее

Comment: а где реализация для `@Autowired private CertificateDao certificateDao;` ?
`

Comment: @Темка  `@Repository` стоит на нем

Comment: как и было предначертано `com.training.dataaccess` не сканируется, так как в нем две **ss**, а сканируется `com.training.dataacces`, который с одной **s**, и реализация не находится при сканировании

Comment: @Темкатоже  я тут даже не знаю что сказать, извини что потратил твое время, спасибо огромное=)

Comment: начни использовать IDEA или eclipse с плагином для spring, там есть автодополнения и прочиеи подсказки, которые помогут тебе не допускать таких ошибок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя есть класс `com.training.services.impl.CertificateServiceImpl` (который ты не привел), в котором есть поле certificateDao, помеченное как @Autowired. При этом его реализации лежит за пределами сканируемых пакетов

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.training.dataacces" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.training.services" />
```

либо реализация не отмечена как `@Component`, либо вообще отсутствует.

---

Вообще странные вещи ты делаешь здесь

```
GroupServiceImpl gService = new GroupServiceImpl();
FacultyServiceImpl fServise = new FacultyServiceImpl();
```

Эти компоненты можно просто внедрить при помощи `@Autowired`. Тем более в них есть поля отмеченные как `@Autowired`, а при использовании конструктора они сами по себе не инициализируются и ты с легкостью словишь `NullPointerException`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь , `gService` и `fServise`  я сразу и помечал как `@Autowired`, но начало падать с этой ошибкой, я подумал что нельзя.. Добавил код `CertificateServiceImpl`